# Digital signature verification failing - Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, verification

I am generating digital signature using below methods with payload as "hello world"

```
public String generateSignature(String payload) throws Exception{
        Signature rsa = null;
        rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA/PSS", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        rsa.initSign(getPrivateKey("Keys/private_key"));
        rsa.update(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(rsa.sign());
        String signature = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signatureBytes);
        return signature;
    }
```

I am validating the signature with payload "hello world" and signature that I got from generateSignatue method.

```
public boolean validateSignature(String payload, String signature) throws Exception {
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA/PSS", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    boolean isValid = false;
    sig.initVerify(getPublicKey("Keys/public_key"));                
    sig.update(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    isValid = sig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(signature.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    return isValid;
}
```

This is always returning isValid as false, what is the mistake?

Retrieving Public key & private key with below functions (for reference):

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String filename) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePublic(spec);
    }

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}
```

Comment: Second paragraph, this line: `isValid = ig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(signature.getBytes("UTF-8")));` 
There is a missing "s" i believe that `ig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(signature.getBytes("UTF-8")));`should be `sig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(signature.getBytes("UTF-8")));` Did you just failed to copy it or ?

Comment: @xoxel yeah it was mistake while copying. corrected it

Comment: Hi @usr_11, did you finally fix the issue?

Comment: @pedrofb yes the issue is fixed. The issue was, I missed to add DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(signature) in validateSignature method

Answer (score 1):

I can see some errors at a glance:

- A DER file contains certificates, not private keys. Do you have a typo at `"Keys/private_key.der"`?
- Your signing code encodes the signature bytes to base64 and hex, but your verification code only decodes from base64. Remove this `String signature = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signatureBytes);` You can also remove the base64 conversion and work in both methods with `byte[]` directly
- Within the edited code the hexadecimals is gone, but you need to use base 64 decoding of the signature. Furthermore you must make sure you use a known good base 64 codec, such as `Base64.getEncoder()` and `Base64.getDecoder()`.

Comment: have removed .der files, have used actual private & public keys. Have worked on byte also as u suggested, but no success.

Comment: Please, update your question with the latest code and the current error

Comment: DER files are not limited to certificates; there are many types including both public and private keys (with _several_ formats of private keys, although Java has good support for only two) and also CRLs and possibly CSRs and messages of various kinds and signatures. PEM files are often better because they tell you (or confirm) what is in them, but that doesn't make DER files impossible or even wrong, especially in Java which doesn't directly support most PEM. (Concur about encoding mismatch.)